# Eternal reminder service

Tags: java, android, service, reminders

I make reminder in my app. User can set time for reminder. How to make eternal service, who will check device time and if it equal user set time - output the notification. I try like this, but it work few times and die. What have I done wrong?

```
void redinder2() {    

for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++) {

  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();    
  hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);   

  if(hour==my_hour&&minute==my_minyte){){    sendNotif();}      

      if(i==10){startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));}
          try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(59);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make an "eternal service", nor would that be the correct approach for this problem. [Only have a service running when it is **actively delivering value to the user**](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html). Watching the clock tick is not actively delivering value to the user.

Use `AlarmManager` to arrange to get control at the time to do the reminder.